# android add live camera effects to custom camera library CameraView

Tags: android, camera, effects

I'm creating an application with the features of live camera effects.
I've used custom camera library ( https://github.com/natario1/CameraView#capturing-video ) for making images and videos.
Now the issue is that I want to apply live camera effects to this camera preview.
Searched alot but couldn't find any solution.
Kindly give your suggestions.

```
cameraView.addFrameProcessor(new FrameProcessor() {
@Override
@WorkerThread
public void process(Frame frame) {
    byte[] data = frame.getData();
    int rotation = frame.getRotation();
    long time = frame.getTime();
    Size size = frame.getSize();
    int format = frame.getFormat();
    // Process...
  }
}
```

this is method for frame processing

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `live camera effects`?

Comment: it means add effects to live camera..like user can add effect to camera preview before capturing image..he can add effect like Retrica and other live editing apps

Comment: too broad. Check open cv for android. also seen people use opengl for the same.

Comment: just take the preview frame, process it the way you need, and show in the `TextureVIew`. WHat exactly is a problem for you to do that?

Comment: using this library I'm unable to get preview frame..
I'm ready to switch my camera from custom camera to camera2 api.
can you help me that how i can process that frame and show in texture view?

Comment: I've found the method of library for frame processing..
I've edited my question with that method.
now kindly tell me that how i can add effect to it..
i want to add thermal effect that is mixture of two colors.yellow and black.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko kindly help with the frame processing.

Comment: you need to edit the `frame.getData()` bytes of the frame the way you need. I have no idea about the *thermal* effect, r any other effects. First you will have to find out how you need to change the bytes, or pixels at least to achieve those effects.

Comment: okay..i'll start doing that..if i'll need help in any case i'll mention you..thanks